# Dreamweaver CC 2017 not consistent when compiling SCSS files

Tags: compilation, sass, dreamweaver

When I open a .scss file and save it Dreamweaver compiles it fine for the first few times.  But after 4-5 saves it stops compiling the CSS and gives me a "Cannot lint the code. Click here for troubleshooting" error.  Then if I quit dreamweaver and then restart it, I can compile 3-4 files then the same error starts up again.  I visited one of dreamweavers help articles that instructed me to create a NodePort.json file and put { “toolingport” : 8010 }  in it and I did but that didn't help.  I would love to use dreamweaver if I can, but I am open to another way to compile scss files if it is easy enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you check out grunt. http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-grunt-and-sass/ - In my humble opinion using Dreamweaver to do anything "tricky" is best avoided... if you get into grunt you'll never look back :)

Especially when you hook it up to LiveReload. At that point you'll save your SCSS (in Dreamweaver) and the browser will automatically refresh showing your changes :) It's magical. (Plus it does lots more)